# Uploading a contract in a Docker environment

Tags: cleos, docker

I have EOS running on Docker and can run cleos successfully.  my next step is to deploy the token contract but looking in the `./contracts/eosio.token` directory I don't see a `.wast` file.

I could create it with `eosiocpp` but I don't seem to have it installed.  so, as per the Docker wiki, I ran the docker build in the `Docker/dev` directory, which created an image `eosio/eos-dev`

now my question: how do I run `eosiocpp` to create the WAST file in my filesystem using Docker?

Comment: How about, if you use one of the prebuild docker images? You can you try to get the docker-image from: https://hub.docker.com/r/eosio/eos-dev/tags/ It includes eosiocpp.

Comment: thanks but my question is: how do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also recommend using the docker [image from docker-hub.](https://hub.docker.com/r/eosio/eos-dev/)

**Pull it** by running the following command:

```
docker pull eosio/eos-dev
```

Now you **create a folder** in your local machine named `Code`
Afterwards you can **start the container** by running it with the following command. This will use your local Code folder and mount it to the filesystem in the docker container.

```
docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -v <path_to_code>/Code:/Code -v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data -v /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config eosio/eos-dev  /bin/bash -c "nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin eosio::wallet_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console"
```

Afterwards you use **aliases for calling cleos and eosiocpp.**

```
alias cleos='docker exec eosio /opt/eosio/bin/cleos --wallet-url http://localhost:8888'

alias eosiocpp='docker exec eosio /opt/eosio/bin/eosiocpp'
```

Now you can start developing and if you want to **compile** your code you can call the eosiocpp alias with your mycontract.cpp file.

```
eosiocpp -o Code/mycontract.wast Code/mycontract.cpp
eosiocpp -g Code/mycontract.abi Code/mycontract.cpp
```

**Pushing** it to the chain can be done by using cleos alias with:

```
cleos set contract mycontract Code/mycontract Code/mycontract.wast Code/mycontract.abi
```

For **debugging** the container this might also help. Which gives you a terminal inside the container.

```
docker exec -i -t eosio /bin/bash
```

And **viewing logs** with:

```
 docker logs --tail 100 eosio
```

Comment: fantastic.  I noticed that the developer portal recommends running EOS the way you indicate but there's a problem: keosd doesn't run and you can't create accounts.  the Docker wiki offers a better solution: download the `docker-compose.yml` and then start both services.  the only thing is eos-dev is not included, though something called eosio/builder is, which seems to be the same thing.  thank you for the complete reply.  it will help anyone else trying to do this

Comment: the container start failed, curiously, not leaving any trace (`docker ps -a` came up empty).  running it with `-it` I had a chance to see the message "database dirty flag set (likely due to unclean shutdown): replay required".  I know how to fix it but I'm wondering why this would happen given that I removed all containers and all images from Docker before starting on your instructions

Comment: also, publishing the contract fails with "Reading WAST/WASM from Code/eosio.token.wast...
Assembling WASM...
Publishing contract...
Error 3200006: invalid http request
Error Details:
The server has rejected the request as invalid!
Please verify this url is valid: http://localhost:8888/v1/wallet/get_public_keys
If the condition persists, please contact the RPC server administrator for localhost!" -- I'm wondering whether it's because I need to create a wallet first, for which I need keosd?

Comment: Abour your first error this is hard to tell because I don't your setup and this maybe some docker specific. About the second error: yes you need the keys for that account and a wallet.

Comment: as breadcrumbs, I figured out the whole Docker workflow.  documented it here: https://medium.com/@ekkis/eos-development-on-docker-3f4eb9b680ec

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have special reason to use your current docker image. It is better to use docker image included in eosjs. eosio.token contract is already deployed when running this docker.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/tree/master/docker

In addition, I recommend that building your own contract in your eos repository and copy result to the docker.

`$ docker cp /your workspace/eos/contracts/your contract/ docker_keosd_1:contracts/your contract/`