# Is "Smart Contract" supported by EOS ? Which Language?

Tags: smart-contract

What is the equivalent platform of Ethereum Smart Contract in EOS ? And by which programming languages we can develop a smart contract? Is there a specific language like Solidity in Ethereum? And is there any demo smart contract for EOS as an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EOS is using a WebAssembly virtual machine to run smart contracts.

By theory you can use any language that will compile into WASM, but the most approved way is to use the **C++ library and the eosiocpp tool** (EDIT this will soon be replaced by the [eosio-cpp tool](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.wasmsdk)).

Please have a look at the official [developer portal](https://developers.eos.io/).

I would also recommend to use the Docker workflow like it is described in the portal or in some [questions here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1552/15) for less configuration and set up effort.

Also the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts) gives multiple examples of possible contracts.
To start learning I would recommend to use a [tutorial](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-create-an-eos-dapp-simple-guide-ddc1e9d05cb2) (**EDIT** this will be deprecated because of [V1.2](http://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.2.0)) - which will also show you what additional libraries are available (like e.g. [eosjs](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs) for frondent-dev or [Demux](https://medium.com/eosio/introducing-demux-deterministic-databases-off-chain-verified-by-the-eosio-blockchain-bd860c49b017) for backend-dev).

Comment: i think `eosiocpp` is deprecated and `wast` is no longer supported (https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.2.0)

Comment: You are right! Did not yet check the release notes from 2 days ago.. Will update the answer.