# Docker commands not returning to prompt

Tags: installation

I'm a CS major who wants to learn EOS dapp development, but I'm still very much a beginner. On my native Ubuntu machine, I ran

```
sudo docker network create eosnetwork
```

after the previous steps in the documentation (https://www.eosdocs.io/dappdevelopment/software/docker) and then

```
sudo docker run --name server --network=eosnetwork --rm -p 7777:7777 -i eosio/eos /bin/bash -c "nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:7777 --access-control-allow-origin=* --http-validate-host=0"
```

and they don't return to prompt after several minutes. Do I have to keep waiting? I hit ctrl-c and now if I run the first one again, it says Error response from daemon: network with name eosnetwork already exists. Do I have to simply wait more? How do I try it again?

Edit: I think those docs are outdated so I was referred to https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs, and I think I successfully followed section 1.3, but in 1.4 I don't have enough physical memory to install CDT. What can I do?

Comment: Did you try `docker logs --tail 10 server` or something similar on another shell window? I estimate EOS is producing blocks, but you won't see it until you look into the logs.

Comment: I opened a new shell after having closed it a while ago, ran `sudo docker start eosio` and your command outputs `Error: No such container: server`. I was following another guide but someone on a Telegram channel referred me to https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs and I followed that one until I got got the part where I have have to set up CDT and was told I don't have enough physical memory.

Comment: Then replace that server with your containers name. For that second part: it is possible that your tries created unused images/containers which will block your memory. Try to find them by running docker ps -a and docker images.

Comment: I figured out that I just had to install cmake (wasn't a space issue). I tried the CDT install again and it got further but gives errors saying unable to find requested Boost libraries and unable to find Boost header file. I then installed Boost with brew but that didn't help.

Comment: You should try to use the eosio/eos-dev image, so you don't have to build the CDT on your own.

Comment: The docs only mention building CDT from source, though. Is CDT included in the eos-dev image? Is there another doc page explaining how to use it? Why do the docs say to build it from source if eos-dev already has it?

Comment: I am currently working with an older version of EOS.IO but there the dev image included the tools. Maybe try to download it and skip the CDT compile stuff. I have documented the workflow for the version here: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/uploading-a-contract-in-a-docker-environment/1552#1552 Maybe you can adapt it to the current version.